# How do we restrict Mongodb's automated caching to a specific collection

Tags: mongodb, caching

We've just started using Mongodb to replace many of the core sql tables in our app. We'd like to use the same Mongodb instance to store data on performance and usage as a replacement for google analytics. However we don't want this collection automatically using up system memory that could have gone to the primary collection.

Is there a way to control mongodb's automated caching functionality?

Comment: MongoDB has no control over its caching, it is entirely OS based on the LRU. I do not beleive any program currently offers that ganular a control over how much memory a single collection on MongoDB can use. You could plan your application very well, with this in mind, as such it should b doable; granted I know little about your use case but still...

Comment: First, you have to understand that we are not talking of caching. The in memory view is more of the reference data, and the data in the files is rather to be seen like a backup of that data. You might want to dig into capped collections, which come with a quasi limitation of RAM they can use. In general, you might want to go with a sharded cluster, putting the analytics database on one shard (small VPS, for example) and the core database on an other.